# Gmapping Map and Scan Misalignment Issue with Ackermann Robot

Tags: gmapping, ros-noetic

I’m encountering an issue with gmapping in ROS where the generated map visually looks good, but when I use it as an occupancy grid with the robot’s actual location, the scan data does not align correctly.

Here’s my setup:

**Robot Base:** I’m working with an Ackermann-based robot.

**Odometry Source:** I have a location system that provides a TF between the world frame and base_link, which I use as my odometry source.

**Transforms:** There’s a static TF between base_link and the LiDAR source of the scan. The TF Tree during mapping looks something like this:

slam_map (1)-> world (2)-> base_link -> LiDAR

where 1 is generated by gmapping and 2 by the location system

Additionally, I’d like to outline my procedure for using the generated map with gmapping as an occupancy grid:

**Map Generation:** I create the map using gmapping. After exploration, I save the map using map_saver as both a PGM file and a YAML file.

**Coordinate System Alignment:** To anchor the map in the same coordinate system as my location, I save the transform from the “world” frame to the “slam_map” before stopping gmapping.

The TF Tree during testing is something like this:

LiDAR <- base_link <-(1) world (2)-> slam_map

where 1 is generated by the location system and 2 is the transform I saved.

The deviation between the occupancy grid and the scan data seems to increase as the robot moves away from the point where I took the TF.

Any insights or suggestions on addressing the misalignment issue and improving the map-to-scan alignment would be greatly appreciated!